# Can't edit table value in phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I've installed phpmyadmin on a AWS Linux instance. I imported a wordpress sql file with my tables. The tables display correctly and I can select one. When I click edit on any values in the table I don't see the row and there is no option to edit. I included a screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Are you editing any single value or entire row?

Comment: Please give the code what you tried.

Comment: I am attempting to edit a single row. I select the wp_options table then attempt to edit 'siteurl' and the result is the image above.